# Coercive operator applied to difference is coercive

Tags: functional-analysis, variational-analysis

The question is from Avner Friedman's *Variational Principles and Free-Boundary Problems*. It goes:

Let $A: X \to X'$ be monotone, hemicontinuous, and continuous on finite dimensional subspaces of the domain $D(A)$ ($X$ is a reflexive Banach space, and $X'$ is its dual).

Then let $K$ be a closed, unbounded, convex subset of $X$.

Suppose there exists a $\phi_{o} \in K$ such that $(1 + \theta) \phi_{o} \in K$ for some $\theta > 0$. Show that the condition

$$
\frac{\langle Av,v\rangle }{|v|} \to \infty \; as \; |v| \to \infty
$$

implies that

$$
\frac{\langle Av - A\phi_{o}, v - \phi_{o} \rangle}{|v|} \to \infty \; as \; |v| \to \infty
$$

Any help with variational inequalities, free boundary problems, and nonlinear-functional analysis would also be helpful, such as books, web resources, lectures, etc.

Comment: The question doesn't really make sense to me, none of the properties of $A$ or $K$ (how do they relate?) are used or relevant. Let $w= v-\phi_o$ then you are looking at
$$\frac{\langle A w,w\rangle}{|w+\phi_o|}≥ \frac{\langle Aw, w\rangle}{|w|+|\phi_o|} $$
now as $|w|\to \infty$ this term gets arbitrarily close to $\frac{\langle Aw,w\rangle}{|w|}$, which goes to $\infty$ by suppostion.

Comment: Yeah, I was also running into that problem. That is how it is posed in the text, and that chapter of that text is particulary dense/confusing/misleading. Anyway, both of my advisors assumed that the convexity of A allowed us to show that $u - \phi_{o}$ was in A, but I believe that that is false as well. Using the triangle inequality makes sense, but it seems like the reverse triangle inequality might make more sense. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: @s.harp: It seems that you have used linearity of $A$, but this is not given.

Comment: @gerw: The dual pair is linear, but I believe A is not necessarily linear, that is correct.